# How to handle project templates in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a (custom) php framework that contains following structure:

```
app
 |-classes
 |-settings
core
 |-classes
modules
index.php
```

- App folder must contain exclusive
  code for the current application. Also contains configuration files.
- Core contains the framework files.
  This folder is common to all projects
  using this framework.
- Modules can contains snippets
  (libraries, extensions) that can be
  common to multiple projects.

This is all stored in my svn. 
Even App folder content is unique for each project, my trunk framework folder contains raw configuration files with some default values.

Then when I need to create a new project based on this framework what I do is create a new folder in my SVN server for it, and using externals I add the **core** and **index.php** files to the project. **app** and **modules** directories are created in the project directory as empty folders and I replicate manually its internal structure.

Right now is the best method I have.

I was wondering if SVN has some script feature I could use to do all this ardous process every time I need to create a new project

**Edit**: I said script, but any other feature SVN could offer me to help me with this is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a simple batch file / shell script with parameters and few svn commands would do just fine here.